# Fitting model to observed data by obtimising parameters using optim() minimising residual sum of squares

Tags: r, optimization, ode, model-fitting

I am trying to fit this very simple 4 species linear Lotka-Volterra competition model to observed data but for some reason when I try the `optim()` function something with regards to `deSolve` seems to fail.

```
# Data
data <- data.frame(Cod = c(0.1966126, 0.1989563, 0.2567677, 0.3158896, 0.4225435, 0.7219856,
                           1.0570824, 0.7266830, 0.6286763, 0.6389475),
                   Herring = c(1.988372, 2.788014, 3.397138, 2.557245, 2.627013, 3.045617, 
                               3.161002, 3.531306, 3.432021, 3.617174),
                   Sprat = c(2.030273, 3.480469, 3.009277, 1.895996, 2.457520, 1.991211, 2.350098,
                             2.118164, 1.693359, 1.869141),
                   Flounder = c(0.4758220, 0.4425532, 0.4185687, 0.4967118, 0.7102515, 0.5733075,
                                0.7404255, 0.5996132, 0.6235977, 0.7187621))
# Model formulation
LLV <- function(time, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    db1.dt = b1*(r1+a11*b1+a12*b2+a13*b3+a14*b4)
    db2.dt = b2*(r2+a22*b2+a21*b1+a23*b3+a24*b4)
    db3.dt = b3*(r3+a33*b3+a31*b1+a32*b2+a34*b4)
    db4.dt = b4*(r4+a44*b4+a41*b1+a42*b2+a43*b3)
    list(c(db1.dt, db2.dt, db3.dt, db4.dt))
  })
}
# Model input and simulation
# Model input
params <- c(r1 = -0.342085, r2 = 0.6855681, r3 = 2.757769, r4 = 0.9744113,
            a11 = -1.05973762, a12 = 0.09577309, a13 = -0.01915480, a14 = 1.36098939,
            a21 = 0.17533326, a22 = -0.32247342, a23 = 0.03111628, a24 = 0.30212711,
            a31 = 0.5303516, a32 = -0.4869761, a33 = -0.3194882, a34 = -1.5089027,
            a41 = 0.004418133, a42 = 0.163716414, a43 = -0.237873378, a44 = -1.519158802)
ini <- c(b1 = data[1,1], b2 = data[1,2], b3 = data[1,3], b4 = data[1,4])
tmax <- 10
t <- seq(1,tmax,0.1)
# Results and first parameter guess is more or less okay
results <- deSolve::ode(y = ini, times = t, func = LLV, parms = params)
matplot(data, pch = 1)
matplot(x = results[,1], y = results[,-1], type = "l", add = TRUE)
```

Here I proceed and write a function that minimises the residual sum of squares that when included in `optim()` with the above initial parameter guess should produce what I am looking for.

```
min.RSS <- function(data, params) {
  output <- deSolve::ode(y = ini, times = t, func = LLV, parms = params)
  predictions <- exp(output[,-1])
  observations <- data
  return(sum((predictions-observations)^2))
}
result <- optim(par = params, fn = min.RSS, data = data)
fit <- deSolve::ode(y = ini, times = t, func = LLV, parms = result$par)
matplot(x = fit[,1], y = fit[,-1], type = "l", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem will be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is a *hard* problem. I agree that you might think that nonlinear optimization should e easy because you have a good starting condition, but you are trying to fit a 20-parameter nonlinear model to 40 data points. I will take a look and see if I can suggest any solutions, but in general this is going to be **very difficult**. Something like MARSS (multivariate autoregressive state space) models might work ... ?

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you ever so much for the response. Yes, perhaps I'm not allowing optim() to efficiently search with 40 data points. I could try to extend the time series but it is usually what fisheries scientists often have to sort of optimise the fit of more complex models like EwE. I could simulate some data if you think that will sort out the problem to fit the in between years adding some a priori uncertainty to the sampling. I know the code for the model could be written as db.dt=(r+Ab)b but I would like to then add some higher order interespecific interactions.

Comment: The HOI would be coded with the form db1.dt=b1(r1+a11b1+a12b2^2...) I will then reapply the optimiser to then have a somewhat "realistic" (as far as the LV model goes) model that I could use to apply an algorithm that finds Nash Equilibrium harvesting rates. I have used more complex models with this algorithm but the modified LV seems perfect for a tutorial describing the whole process. But the step I am struggling with is this fitting as LV parameters in normal tutorials are quite cryptic for students usually and perhaps having a real system will ease the process of understanding.

Comment: I will have a look at MARSS and thank you again for taking the time to assist/suggest solutions. I really enjoy reading your work :)!

Comment: see my edits: I don't want to rain on your parade, but this model is sufficiently complex that using it to make predictions about what will happen in a fishery is extremely ill-advised - let alone making the more model complex by adding HOIs ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a better fit, but you should be very careful with this problem. I went a little crazy and used the (in-development) [fitode package](https://github.com/parksw3/fitode) to tackle this problem. I fitted the model and got a much better fit, also tried fitting with 100 randomly varying starting points around my best fit.  Your residual sum of squares was 1.19; `fitode` got to 0.29 on the first try, and the best of 100 fits was RSS=0.16. **However**: these fits are *highly* unstable. This plot shows the fits to the data and predictions 5 time steps in the future for (1) your fit (dashed lines); (2) fitode initial fit (dotted line); (3) the 100 other fitode fits (the ones within 0.05 RSS of the best fit are solid, the ones worse than that are drawn very lightly).

You can see that the out-of-sample predictions are mostly crazy. Your fit is actually *more* stable than some of the better fits - it gets to time step 13 before the entire community crashes - but the bottom line is that a good fit to the data in this case **in no way guarantees a sensible answer**. It looks like a single one of the 100 fits reaches the end of the prediction time series without collapsing (which seems like a reasonably sensible "common sense" prediction based on the observed time series).

In order to fit these data reliably, you either need a model with many fewer parameters, or external information supplied in the form of priors, or **regularization** - some way to make penalize fits that imply 'wiggly' deterministic trajectories, or interaction parameters/growth rates that are unreasonable.

[image]

```r
## remotes::install_github("parksw3/fitode")
library(fitode)

## data with tags for fitode
data2 <- setNames(data,paste0(names(data),"_obs"))
data2 <- data.frame(times=seq(nrow(data2)),data2)


## Model formulation (for fitode)
LV_model <- odemodel(
    name="4-species LV",
    model=list(
        Cod ~ Cod*(r1+a11*Cod+a12*Herring+a13*Sprat+a14*Flounder),
        Herring ~ Herring*(r2+a22*Herring+a21*Cod+a23*Sprat+a24*Flounder),
        Sprat ~ Sprat*(r3+a33*Sprat+a31*Cod+a32*Herring+a34*Flounder),
        Flounder ~ Flounder*(r4+a44*Flounder+a41*Cod+a42*Herring+a43*Sprat)
    ),
    observation=list(
        Cod_obs ~ ols(mean=Cod),
        Herring_obs ~ ols(mean=Herring),
        Sprat_obs ~ ols(mean=Sprat),
        Flounder_obs ~ ols(mean=Flounder)
    ),
    initial=list(
        Cod ~ data2$Cod_obs[1],
        Herring ~ data2$Herring_obs[1],
        Sprat ~ data2$Sprat_obs[1],
        Flounder ~ data2$Flounder_obs[1]
    ),
    link=setNames(rep("identity",length(pars)),pars),
    par= pars
)

## plot results
plotres <- function(p,ODEint="rk",lty=1,
                    dt=0.1,
                    tvec=seq(1,10,by=dt),...) {
    par(las=1, bty="l")
    res <- deSolve::ode(ini, tvec, LLV, p, method=ODEint)
    matplot(res[,1],res[,-1],type="l",lty=lty,...)
    return(invisible(res[,-1]))
}

f1 <- fitode(
    LV_model,
    data=data2,
    start=params,
    control=list(maxit=1e5,trace=1000)
)

## fitode with multistart

ranfit <- function(n,fit,range=0.5) {
    ## 
    rpars <- params*runif(length(params),1-range,1+range)
    newfit <- try(update(fit, start=rpars))
    return(newfit)
}

cl <- makeCluster(10)
clusterSetRNGStream(cl = cl, 101)
clusterExport(cl, c("params","LV_model","data2"))
clusterEvalQ(cl,invisible(library(fitode)))
system.time(
    multifit <- parLapply(cl, 1:100, ranfit, fit=f1, tvec=tvec)
)
saveRDS(multifit,file="SO65440448_multifit.rds")

ivec <- seq_along(multifit)
ivec <- ivec[sapply(multifit,function(x) !inherits(x,"try-error"))]
coef <- pred <- vector("list", length=length(ivec))
ll <- conv <- rep(NA,length(ivec))
for (i in seq_along(ivec)) {
    nf <- multifit[[ivec[i]]]
    coef[[i]] <- coef(nf)
    pp <- predict(nf, times=1:10)
    pred[[i]] <- cbind(times=pp[[1]][,1],
                do.call(cbind,lapply(pp,"[",-1)))
    ll[i] <- logLik(nf)
    conv[i] <- nf@mle2@details$convergence
}

par(las=1,bty="l")
matplot(pred[[1]][,1],pred[[1]][,-1],
        type="n",lty=1,ylim=c(0,6),
        xlab="time",ylab="density")
lthresh <- 0.05
for (i in 1:length(pred)) {
    good <- ll[i]>(max(ll)-lthresh)
    alpha <- if (good) 0.8 else 0.1
    lwd <- if (good) 2 else 1
    matlines(pred[[i]][,1],pred[[i]][,-1],lty=1,
             col=adjustcolor(palette()[1:4],alpha.f=alpha),
             lwd=lwd)
}
matpoints(data2[,1],data2[,-1],pch=16,cex=3)
plotres(optimres$par,add=TRUE, lwd=3,lty=2,dt=1)
plotres(coef(f1),add=TRUE, lwd=3,lty=3,dt=1)
```

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks for the thorough answer. I will play around with the `fitode` package reducing the dimensionality of the problem to 2 species with a time series of 46 years. I know that this very simple LV competition model is not great to make deterministic predictions. I am using it to introduce a novel algorithm because is a very simple (phenomenological) model describing spp. interactions (reason why I did not spend to much time making a fancy fitting optimiser). Now that I know that such tools exist in `R` already I will used them and get back to you via this post soon.

Comment: 46 year with 2 species might work OK, especially if you start a simulation reasonably far from equilibrium (so that both the growth parameters (r_i) and the competition parameters (alpha_ij) are identifiable)

Answer (score 1):

To those interested I have managed to get a solution that involves changing the ode integration method. Here is the working optimiser:

```
# Optimising parameter fit
LVmse = function(parms) {
  out = as.matrix(deSolve::ode(ini, 1:10, LLV, parms, method="rk")[,-1])
  RSS = sum((spp-out)^2, na.rm = TRUE) # Minimising residual sum of squares
  return(RSS)
}
optimres <- optim(par = params, fn = LVmse)
```

Comment: When I run this it stops at max iterations=501 with convergence code 1 ('not converged') ...